# How to run async code inside each() function?

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I need to be able to run async code inside the each loop, and not iterate until the async code has finished .

```
$("#items").children(".block-option-small").each(function(item) {
    request(newurl,function(err, resp, body) {  $ = cheerio.load(body);});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [async's whilst function](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst):

```
var async = require("async"),
    request = require("request");

var items, count;

items = $("#items").children(".block-option-small");
count = 0;

async.whilst(
    function() {
        return count < items.length;
    },
    function(whilstCallback) {
        var item;

        item = items[count];
        count++;

        // build request url...

        request(newurl, function(err, resp, body) {
            $ = cheerio.load(body);

            // more processing...

            // process the next item
            whilstCallback();
        });
    },
    function(err) {
        // called when all items have been processed
    }
);
```

Comment: Why `whilst` and not `eachSeries`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the module just for this. You could also write it like this;

```
var items = $("#items").children(".block-option-small");
var count = items.length;

(function iterate(i) {
  if (i === count) {
    // iterations complete
    // do what you want to once iterations are complete
    process.exit(1);
  }

  var item = items[i];

  // async code
  request(newurl, function (err, resp, body) {
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    iterate(i+1);
  });
})(0);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would suggest using `i+1` instead of `++i`.  The latter implies that you're depending on the side-effect of the pre-increment, which isn't true.